# Doctrine Scheme tool with ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to use the Doctrine Scheme tool with ZF2 without much success, I am trying to update my Mysql DB via command line but I keep getting this error:

> > $ ./doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                            The
> >     table with name 'ondemand_server.rbu_roles' already exists.

The rbu_roles is from ZfcRbac and I would imagine it is defined in the vendor module as well as in my own custom modules, how do I deal with this? Is there a way to ignore certain entities etc?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your entity annotations, if you have done some copy/paste, you might have a duplication of the table name:

`@ORM\Table(name="rbu_roles")`

Comment: You were right on this - when I first started using Doctrine I had created a duplicate table not realising that one of the others did exactly the same thing...